# gcm registration null after install the app first time

Tags: android

i need to get gcm registration to a string variable within activity just after installation but i got null value instead of that onRegistered of GCMIntentService class registration shows but not assigning to variable in activity only at first launch of install after second launch working fine

Comment: how are we suppose to help you with no code?

Answer (score 0):

You may check first that if you get register id or not. If you did not get registerID, you can request again for registerId else you can register with RegisterID.